# How to conform two repositories that work on the same entity but have different methods?

Tags: use-case, clean-architecture, repository-pattern

I have to implement 2 use cases, the first one is going to create a **Company** profile from its document number, so inside the use case, it reaches out to the third party API that contains information about the company (as a repository), gets the company data, saves to the local DB (as another repository implementation) and then returns the newly created entity.

something like this:

```
class CreateCompanyFromDocument {
    constructor(
        private companyReadRepositoryInterface: companyReadRepositoryInterface,
        private companyWriteRepositoryInterface: companyWriteRepositoryInterface,
    ) { }

    execute(document: string): Company {

        const document = CompanyDocument:: fromString(document) //value object

        const company = this.companyReadRepositoryInterface.findByDocument(document);
        if (company === null) {
            throw new Error('could not find company by document, creation failed');
        }

        this.companyWriteRepositoryInterface.create(company);
        return company;
    }
}
```

the second use case is to retrieve the created company (of the local DB) by its ID (a UUID generated at the creation process), so it reaches out to the local DB (as a repository) and returns the Company entity if it founds it.

```
class GetCompanyById {
    constructor(private companyReadRepository: companyReadRepositoryInterface) { }

    execute(id: string): Company {

        const company = this.companyReadRepository.findById(id);
        if (company === null) {
            throw new Error('could not find company by id');
        }
        return company;
    }
}
```

the problem:

the repository implementation of the third party API only supports retrieval by the document (*findByDocument*) and does not support creation or retrieval by id (*create*, *findById*), the implementation of the local DB supports all functionalities.

one of my ideas was to use a *CQS*-ish approach and create a **companyReadRepositoryInterface**, **companyWriteRepositoryInterface** and **CompanyRepositoryInterface** that would extend the read and write, but this still would not have solved the problem because the API implementation would still have to implement the *findById()* method.

I thought about creating different Entities for each, but the **Company** entity, properties, and behavior are the same no matter the repository.

I also thought about just throwing an Exception in the find *findById()* implementation of the API repository, breaking the interface segregation principle, and possibly several others...

I know i specified a lot of specific technical implementation details and should focus mostly on abstraction, it's just for you to have a better idea of the problem.

How can i solve this?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, I meant "interface segregation principle", I mean, I'm extending an interface that has no true behavior, that does not seem a good design to me, but it's a easy solution

Comment: The ISP isn't broken by throwing an exception in an interface implementation. It is broken when you design a read interface with two methods findByDocument and findById which cannot always be sensibly implemented by all clients. So that's indeed the case here, see my answer how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you need are two different "read" interfaces - one for repositories which can handle a document number, and one which can handle a UUID for local storage access.

So you could make a

```
  companyReadFromDocumentRepoInterface
```

which provides `findByDocument`, and two interfaces

```
  companyReadFromDatabaseRepoInterface
  companyWriteToDatabaseRepoInterface
```

for `findById` and `create`. In case you don't have a use case where you really need the two latter interfaces separated, just merge them into one

```
  companyDatabaseRepoInterface
```

which supports both, `create` as well as `findById`. Or keep them separated (but not because someone invented the name  "interface seggregation principle", but because merging them into one causes real issues in your code).

Comment: thanks, it solves the problem but it seems that I do not have a strong "contract" and for every specific need of a repository I need to create a new interface.

Comment: @ThiagoDias: I would not jump to conclusions. I guess here you need one type of repo for each category of storage providers (like databases and document-centric APIs). But in reality, I would expect the number of these categories to stay small.

Comment: @ThiagoDias: Yeah. Trying to shoehorn two out-of-process/remote data sources behind a single interface is probably not a good idea if those two data sources are different enough that doing so can impact performance or usability of your code. The abstractions that you come up with should not ignore real-world considerations; they are abstractions in the sense that they *represent* aspects of the system, including real-world constraints, in an abstract way. Your use cases will have certain constraints and access patterns - and you can categorize your repositories according to that.

Comment: @ThiagoDias P.S. In situations where it's important to make a distinction between different kinds of repos, having different interfaces also communicates to the other devs (and your future self) that one kind of repository isn't meant to be used in the same way as some other kind. The *code* that obtains the entities from the repos shouldn't know how the repos work, it's the code that you want to decouple - but the *developers* writing the code should have some idea about the tradeoffs involved with each kind of repo.